# Form ready / init event on Ninja Forms - Backbone / Marionette

Tags: javascript, wordpress, backbone.js, marionette, ninja-forms

I am currently working with the "NinjaForms" plugin for WordPress, which provides custom form management for the backend. It's based on Marionette / Backbone JS. After some research, I had no problem triggering JavaScript functions on input change and on form submit. However, I have not found a way to fish for an event once the form is initialised / rendered / shown (any of these, really).

What I am doing right now is initialising a Marionette object, adding listeners to a radio and then adding functions to execute it on event:

```
if(typeof Marionette !== 'undefined') {
    var mySubmitController = Marionette.Object.extend( {
        initialize: function() {
            // init listener
            this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'forms' ), 'view:show', this.initAction);
            // field change listener
            this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'fields' ), 'change:modelValue', this.valueChanged);
            // submit listener
            this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'forms' ), 'submit:response', this.actionSubmit );
        },

        // init action
        initAction: function() {
            console.log("init");
        },

        // input update action
        valueChanged: function(model) {
            console.log("update");
        },

        // submit action
        actionSubmit: function( response ) {
            // handled via php

            console.log("submit");
        },
    });

    // initialise listening controller for ninja form
    new mySubmitController();
}
```

However, the line `this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'forms' ), 'view:show', this.initAction);` is not working. I have tried the events `view:render`, `view:show`, `show:view`, `render:view` without success.

I searched in the Backbone / Marionette documentations,  but could not find a fitting event. This question might be a duplicate, but I could not really find any topic regarding form initialisation events with Backbone.

Comment: you are settle handlers for two channels.
if this channels stays idlle - means there is no events you are listening then you never see your console.log messages. You can check handler like that: Backbone.Radio.channel('forms').trigger('view:show') - this should output to console "init".
if you do not see any logs in console it means that: a) first if statement is false and your mySubmitController not created. b) your events never triggered on that channels

Comment: and of course you should include `backbone.radio` lib

Comment: I don't want to trigger events manually, I want to listen to an event that's fired once the form is rendered, so that I can then manipulate the form DOM with Javascript. However, the triggering does output "init" into the console.

Comment: i just tell you that if nobody triggers the event - it will not rised.
if you expect that, say ninjaforms, triggers that events for you then a) it not  happens, b) ninja triggers other events you are not listening, c) your if statement is false

Comment: and of course there is no any special triggers for form rendering by default.

Comment: The if statement is working properly. I am looking for the specific event Ninjaforms and/or Backbone and/or Marionette is firing, that's why I created this question in the first place...

Comment: check: 
1) are you included `backbone.radio` before `backbone.marionette` script
2) ninja documentation for clarifying is there any triggers for those events.

Backbone and Backbone marionette do not triggers any events, the only place it can be done - ninja forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after some long search, googling and frustration I've found a solution. Using the following JavaScript-Code, you can execute code on form render:

```
// if there is a ninja form on this page
if(typeof Marionette !== 'undefined') {
    var mySubmitController = Marionette.Object.extend( {
        initialize: function() {
            // init listener
            this.listenTo( nfRadio.channel( 'form' ), 'render:view', this.initAction );
        },

        // init action
        initAction: function() {
            // code to execute on form render
        },
    });

    // initialise listening controller for ninja form
    new mySubmitController();
}
```

Comment: Where do you put the JS? In script tags on the wordpress page or somewhere else?

Comment: @Svante I'm implementing a scripts.js file via functions.php, that's where I put my code.

Comment: Thanks, I found this very helpful: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: I needed to add `nf-front-end` as a dependency when enqueuing my script in `functions.php` to ensure it was loaded after Marionette.

Comment: I believe you can also use `this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'forms' ), 'init:model', this.actionLoad );`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to implement some JS after Ninja Forms init and this method worked for me.

```js
if (typeof Marionette !== 'undefined') {
    var mySubmitController = Marionette.Object.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(nfRadio.channel('form'), 'render:view', this.initAction);
        },
        initAction: function () {
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                jQuery('#nf-field-364,#nf-field-329,#nf-field-302,#nf-field-284').on('input', function () {
                    jQuery(this).trigger('change')
                })
            })
        },
    });
    new mySubmitController();
}
```